# How check from where(sources) data come to table Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

How check from where(sources) data come to table Oracle 11g.
I have table. Some sources insert data to it. I need find all sources.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want.  Do you want to audit records as they are being inserted to the table ?  Do you want to find out which users/processes access the table over a period of time ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the grants on the table - which database users have the rights to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Check all software that can connect as those users. Good luck.